# Infected by OR with love?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, by-with

Is it:

The crazed ramblings of a man entirely infected by love OR The crazed ramblings of a man entirely infected with love?

Comment: It depends on what you mean: is love the infection or the agent of infection? A man may be infected with rabies by a dog. Are you sure that “to infect” is the best verb here?